# Primary directory not allowed for content://media/external/images/media/296; allowed directories are [DCIM, Pictures]

Tags: android, mediastore, scoped-storage

I was trying to rename a photo file in android api level > 28 (Pie) and getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary directory WhatsApp not allowed for content://media/external/images/media/296; allowed directories are [DCIM, Pictures] exception

Below is the code for fetching images from storage

```
private fun getAllImages(): List<ImageModel>? {
    val allImagesUri = getExternalUriForImages()
    val columns = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT, MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH)
    val cursor = application.contentResolver.query(allImagesUri, columns, null, null, null)
    return prepareImageModel(cursor)
}

private fun prepareImageModel(cursor: Cursor?):List<ImageModel>?{
    var images :MutableList<ImageModel>? = null
    if (cursor != null && cursor.count > 0) {
        images = mutableListOf()
        val idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
        val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
        val dateAddedIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED)
        val dateModifiedIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED)

        for (i in 0 until cursor.count) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i)
            val id = cursor.getLong(idColumnIndex)
            if (id != -1L) {
                val name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
                val dateAdded = cursor.getString(dateAddedIndex)
                val dateModified = cursor.getString(dateModifiedIndex)
                val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(getExternalUriForImages(), id)
                val imageModel = ImageModel(id, name, dateAdded, dateModified, uri = uri)
                images.add(imageModel)
            }
        }
    }
    return images
}

fun getExternalUriForImages(): Uri {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL) else {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    }
}

data class ImageModel(var id: Long, var name: String?, var dateAdded: String? = "",
                      var dateModified: String? = "", var resolution: String? = "", var uri: Uri)
```

Below is the code for renaming a file

```
private fun renameFile(imageModel: ImageModel?) {
    if(imageModel != null){
        try {
            // When performing a single item update, prefer using the ID
            val selection = "${MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID} = ?"
            // By using selection + args we protect against improper escaping of // values.
            val selectionArgs = arrayOf(imageModel.id.toString())
            // Update an existing file.
            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "New name ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
            }

            // Use the individual song's URI to represent the collection that's
            // updated.
            val rowsUpdated = contentResolver.update(imageModel.uri, contentValues, selection, selectionArgs)
            Toast.makeText(this, if(rowsUpdated > 0) "Rename success" else "Rename failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } catch (securityException: SecurityException) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                val recoverableSecurityException = securityException as?
                        RecoverableSecurityException ?:
                throw RuntimeException(securityException.message, securityException)
                val intentSender = recoverableSecurityException.userAction.actionIntent.intentSender
                intentSender?.let {
                    pendingImageModel = imageModel
                    startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_RENAME_FILE, null, 0, 0, 0, null)
                }
            } else {
                throw RuntimeException(securityException.message, securityException)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SimplePhotoApp">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Well.. what do you want? I see no question. Put all in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: I am getting exception and not able to rename a file. How can I rename file on api level > 28.

Comment: `imageModel.uri` We cannot see what uri you use. Nor where it comes from. Please upfdayte your code to make that clear.

Comment: imageModel.uri is content uri of a file nothing else

Comment: Then put in your code which value it has as all depends on the used content scheme. You could do that adding the code where you call your renameFIle function. Also tell in which classic folder -full path- the file resides.

Comment: I have updated my code. Now you can find all the code from fetching images to renaming a file.

Comment: Much too much code. I did not ask for that. And nowhere you call renameFile(). I only asked you to show how you called renameFile with the used value for the uri. That was all. One code line would have done.

Comment: I don't know how can i help you to understand the problem. Everything is in front of you and I am calling renameFile method from recyclerview adapter by clicking on rename button on recycler view item. Do you still want me to post that code also?

Comment: No of course not. I only asked for one, two tree lines of code where you show how you call renameFile with the used uri value. Like imageModel.uri= "content:...."; renameFIle(imageModel);. Thats was all. That is all.